# Tkinter frame auto scaling to largest frame size, not relative

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

when I'm dealing with Tkinter frames, the main start screen I am on is auto setting the size to the largest of my frames sizes, I would like it to stay relative to the frame you are currently on if possible?
enter image description here[image]

[image]

The code I'm using for creating the root is -

```
def raise_frame(frame):
frame.tkraise()

root = Tk()
root.title("CRM Program")
root.resizable(False, False)
```

Comment: You are presumably using the common approach of having all of your Frames actually present in the root window at the same time, and just raising the one you want to see.  (I personally don't like this approach, as it's possible to tab into an Entry on one of the hidden Frames, and accidentally type text into a field you can't even see.).  With all of the Frames present, all of their sizes will be taken into account when sizing the window.  What you want instead is to only have one Frame part of the window at a time - call `.grid_forget()` on the rest.

Comment: Yeah I am currently just raising each frame as you said, I didn’t realise you may run into problems like that.

Comment: I will give your way a go and let you know how I get on, thank you for the advice. I appreciate it